# Do lithium ion batteries double effective performance every 18 month similar to Moore's law?

Tags: technology, energy, battery

On [Quora](http://qr.ae/NJ641) a person claims that lithium ion batteries improve roughly similar to Moore's law:

> The installed price of lithium ion batteries is dropping in half every 18 months and they last twice as long ... just like Moore's law for computer chips... 
>   well not quite Moore's law but something very similar.

Is that claim accurate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that claim is highly inaccurate. I'm guessing that it's somehow related to the part of a talk that was widely quoted (also by mainstream media):

> Shai Agassi, the founder and former CEO of Better Place, also touted
>   the importance of the rate of battery innovation during his talk at
>   the Cleantech Investor Summit. He said the energy density of batteries
>   goes up 15 percent every 18 months; the cost per kilowatt hour goes
>   down 15 percent every 18 months; the life cycles of the batteries (how
>   many times it can charge and recharge) goes up 15 percent every 18
>   months; and the cost per lifecycle-mile does down 50 percent every 18
>   months. “If you don’t like the margins in this [electric car] business
>   just wait 12 months,” said Agassi.

Thus this directly contradicts both claims about the cost and how long they last. I don't really know what "cost per lifecycle-mile" is supposed to mean.

Comment: I think "cost per lifecycle-mile" is the manufacturing cost divided by the number of miles you might expect to drive before the batteries no longer take a useful charge and need to be completely replaced (the average number of miles driven per recharge multiplied by the number of recharge cycles).  It may also include recharging costs, but I doubt it.